# Android Vertical tabhost

Tags: android, android-tabhost, vertical-alignment

i want to built a vertical Tab host like the below image

[image]

i tried with the following code but the tabs are not visible

```
getTabWidget().setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

is it possible to implement tab host like below.if possible tell me the way to implement tab host like below.and also post the links if there are any built in project's to implement it like the below Image.
(or)
is it possible to add an activity to image view click similar to tab bar click like below

```
  mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(R.id.textview1));
```

because if it is possible i will put image views and change the activities on each item click

Help me out in making the vertical tab-host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to place your tab Widget in a horizontal `LinearLayout` in your XML file:

```
<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView3" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        </TabWidget>

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

this will place the tabs to the right of the content, if you want it to the left you need to rearrange the order in the XML file.

Comment: is that viewpager and framelayout even required?

Answer (score 2):

Better use fragments. Make a layout with vertically aligned buttons and use fragments for transition of pages on button click. [Refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to know more about fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement Emil Adz answer.

When you add the control to the layout using the graphic tool, this adds all the code necessary for it, but it misses `android:orientation="vertical"` for every LinerLyout.

Example:

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 >
            </LinearLayout>
```

You have to type it down yourself

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
```